# Java web server to process Android client request

Tags: java, android, webserver

Since I'm a newbie to Java web server, I don't know where to begin to create a server in Java to reply from Android devices request( **A WEB SERVER NOT AN ACTUAL SITE)**.

Which technology should I use and which document should i read?. I have searched on the Internet about Java but i found out many technologies and i don't know which one i can use.

Spring MVC,JSF,JSP,Struts,Servlet..............

Hope this question clear enough for you to reply. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what be process android devices requests on server side. In this case main idea is http communication - client sends request, server process this request and sends response to client, and you can use any technology on server side - java, php etc. 
If you prefer java I can suggest you try servlets, it is simplest technology of those you mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you.I know i can use the only Servlet to build. But what if i want to use a framework, does it faster or the same?When do i need to use a Java framework? I have .Net background

Comment: You can also have a ASP.NET MVC WebApp responding to Android.

Comment: BigMike:Thanks for reply. A .Net MVC is a good choice. But my project is required to build by Java web server ^^

Comment: To use servlets or any web framework you minimum need servlet-container (tomcat, jetty) to launch your servlets. All java web frameworks anyway based on servlets and servlets technologies (like filters) Try to find servlets tutorial and create your servlet + jsp for example, if it would be simple you can try to use some framework.